# add sequence of date into dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame as follows:

```
country   day     value

AE        1        23
AE        2        30
AE        3        21
AE        4        3
BD        1        2
BD        2        23
...       ..       ..
BD        22       23
```

I want to populate the date column into my data frame from the starting date of 2020-08-01 end 2020-08-21
for each group.
Here is my attempt :

```
values = seq(from = as.Date("2020-08-01"), to = as.Date("2020-08-21"), by = 'day')
df<- df %>% group_by(country) %>% mutate(date=values)
```

but it does not give me the proper result.

Here is the result that I want :

country   day     value        date

```
AE        1        23      2020-08-01
AE        2        30      2020-08-02
AE        3        21      2020-08-03
AE        4        3       2020-08-04
BD        1        2       2020-08-01
BD        2        23      2020-08-02
...       ..       ..
BD        21       23      2020-08-21
```

could you please let me know how can I solve this problem.
here is the error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `date`.
x Input `date` can't be recycled to size 23.
ℹ Input `date` is `seq(...)`.
ℹ Input `date` must be size 23 or 1, not 23.
ℹ The error occured in group 22: country = "CU".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the 'values' are created without any grouping.  We could either do a `group_by` and create the `seq`uence of 'date' within each 'country', specifying the `length.out`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    mutate(date=seq(from = as.Date("2020-08-01"), length.out = n(), 
          by = 'day'))
```

In a large dataset, it is possible to have different 'country' to have different number of frequency.  So, it would be better to use `length.out` instead of the `to` option

---

If the 'country' length are all the same and is the same length as 'values', we don't need to create `group_by`, the 'values' can be `rep`licated

```
df %>%
    mutate(date = rep(values, length.out = sum(county == first(country))))
```